# Accessing a variable in the first frame via an external action script file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Background:

I have a project where i need to create multiple objects that consume the same base calss from an external .as file.

each of the individual fla files that consume the base class need to pass a variable to the base class so the class can return information specific to the fla.

My question is,

if i have an external class path set up,  how do i get a variable on the first frame of the movie to be visible to the base class && how do i call upon its value from within the class.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All stage instances that are on the stage in Frame 1 are accessible to the main document Class in the constructor.

So:

```
package {
   public class YourChildClass extends MovieClip {
      protected var _something:String;
      public function get something():String {
         return _something;
      }
      public function set something(value:String): void {
         _something=value;
         //do something with the value, like setting a text field's text
      }
   }
}

package {
   public class MainDocument extends MovieClip {
      public var child1:YourChildClass;
      public var child2:YourChildClass;
      public var child3:YourChildClass;
      public function MainDocument() {
         child1.something='hello';
         child2.something='world';
         child3.something='!';
      }
   }
}
```

For more information, see http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html

Answer (score -1):

SomeBaseClass.as

```
public class SomeBaseClass
{
    protected var sharedVariable:String = "";

    public function SomeBaseClass()
    {
    }
}
```

SomeSubClass.as

```
public class SomeSubClass extends SomeBaseClass
{
    public function SomeSubClass()
    {
        super.sharedVariable = "some value";
    }
}
```

Comment: The main Document Class can't access protected variables.